# ClickOnce signing via Azure Key Vault

Tags: wpf, jenkins, clickonce, azure-keyvault

Got a question regarding click once signing.

I have a server with Jenkins on it, which handles building a WPF application with ClickOnce as a deployment option. I have used a set of commands for MSBuild and mage.exe to produce an application file with deployment and application manifests signed by a provided *.pfx file.

Now the decision was made that the pfx file will not be provided. Instead, all keys were moved to the Azure Key Vault.

My question is - what will be a correct flow to make manifest signing for the ClickOnce application work with Azure Key Vault? I just don't understand how to execute the mage -update correctly with no path to provide as -certfile argument.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Can [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-keyvault/) help you?

Comment: Thank you, saw that plugin. What I'm failing to understand is how would it store the acquired pfx file. I assume it writes it somewhere and cleans it up after the build is finished.

Comment: This one could also be nice to look into: https://github.com/dotnet/SignService/blob/master/src/SignService/SigningTools/MageSignService.cs

Comment: Why don't you provide the `.pfx` as a secret file or whatever it's called in Jenkins?

Comment: @mm8 The IT department won't provide that to me. For some reason, they don't want the key to be stored anywhere else outside the KeyVault (

Comment: Key Vault isn't really set up to act as PKI, so even if you have access to get the key, the private key material is never returned to you currently. Operations using the private key such as signing, if you have permissions, are done in Key Vault itself so hypothetically, you could build PKI atop Key Vault. See https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool for an example that effectively replaces signtool.exe, but you would need to adapt it to sign a ClickOnce manifest which, to my knowledge, only mage.exe can do. Might be other OSS tools out there from which to borrow code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code here:

https://github.com/davici-code/AzureSignToolClickOnce

to succesfully sign ClickOnce applications in Azure DevOps with a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault.

> It signs all the required executables and manifest files. Internally
> AzureSignTool is used to sign the executables and the mage code signs
> the manifest with Authenticode.

https://www.davici.nl/blog/clickonce-signing-from-azure-devops-via-azure-key-vault

For Jenkins it would also work.